# Extruding geometry along normals

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to figure out a method how to extrude along normals as the Square Example which shows the extrusion mesh going along perfectly its geometry axis.

On the shape which I'm trying to extrude no matter if I choose to extrude faces along normals, or try to hit <kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to extrude, it's distorting the extruded faces like the example in the screenshots.

So what's the best method to get the extruded mesh to follow correctly along its original geometry axis?

[image]

[image]

Comment: hello, could you please share your file?

Comment: Here's the file:

[<img src="https://blend-exchange.com/embedImage.png?bid=kdvXZAea" />](https://blend-exchange.com/b/kdvXZAea/)

Comment: Your selection looks like a curve, so the extrutions is going to be curved, you could move the vertices to make a straight selection and then extrude.

Comment: I think he precisely wants the extrusion to follow the original curvy shape, not sure it's possible, as extrude along faces normal do not give the good result

Comment: Which method would be correct to follow for this type of extrusion?